# Jquery Mobile - changing icon color in header from some other button click

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to change color of icon in header from some button click.

I was able to put some color on icon using below CSS: 
 #myhead:after {
            background-color: #ff4d4d;
        }

But i am not able to change its color from some button click.

Sample Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>

        /* #id Products */
         #myhead:after {
            background-color: #ff4d4d;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
    function changecolor()
    {
        $('#myhead:after').css("background-color", "green");
        }
    </script>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">

    <div data-role="header"  class=" ui-icon-circle ui-alt-icon ui-btn-icon-right " id="myhead">
    <h3>Filter</h3>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn" onclick="changecolor()">Change Color</a>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate **css:after**, because it's not technically part of the **DOM** and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. So you need to create custom circle icon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
 .change-color {
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin: -30px 10px 0px 0px;
 }
</style>

<script>
 function changecolor() {
    $('#myhead').css('background-color', 'green');
 }
</script>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="header" class="">
        <h3>Filter</h3>
        <div class="change-color" id="myhead"></div>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn" onclick="changecolor()">Change Color</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS as below

```
#myhead h3 {
     background-color: #ff4d4d;
}
```

And change the JS as below

```
$('#myhead h3').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Comment: My query was about changing icon color and not header color. However Thanks for the information Mahendra.